# How to extract and replace not lower case letters in a file using python code?

Tags: python

I am able to extract and replace the Directory names by using below code, but same way iwould like change the paths in a file. How do we do?

```
count = 1
temp = os.walk(folder_path, topdown=False)
for root, dirs, files in temp:
    for i in dirs:
        source = os.path.join(root, i)
        Upper_chars = ''.join(x for x in i if not x.islower())#extract upper, characters
        if len(Upper_chars) > 1:
            try:
                Destination = os.path.join(root, Upper_chars)
                os.rename(source, Destination)
            except FileExistsError:
                Destination = os.path.join(Destination, str(count))
                os.rename(source, Destination)
                count = count + 1

print('All Directories Renamed')
```

Similar way i have a txt file, that is having the paths like,

```
a.txt
"{root}/Folder_A/Sub_Folder_A1/Sub_Folder_A2",
"{root}/Folder_B/Sub_Folder_B1/Sub_Folder_B2",
"{root}/Folder_C/Sub_Folder_C1/Sub_Folder_C2"
```

to be changed to

```
"{root}/F_A/S_F_A1/S_F_A2",
"{root}/F_B/S_F_B1/S_F_B2",
"{root}/F_C/S_F_C1/S_F_C2"
```

Note: I am new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to open file use `open()` then use regex `[a-z]+_` to replace lowercase before the `_`

```
import re

with open('a.txt','r') as f: # `r` for read file
    newText = re.sub(r'[a-z]+_', '_', f.read()) # replace lowercase
    
    # save results
    with open('a-result.txt', 'w') as g: # `w` for write file
        g.write(newText)
```

Comment: Thank you, It replaces the {root} to {}.

Comment: without underscore or `[a-z]+` it will replace any lower chars